# How to regexp replace mySQL column before matching?

Tags: php, mysql, regex

How can I use regular expressions in MySQL to rewrite the column value to be matched with an exact string? I can only find guides that do the opposite.

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE regexp_replace('([^0-9])', '', phone) = '0123456789';
```

The reason is that the column can contain all kinds of formatting e.g. "012-345 6789" "(0)12-3456789" and so on...

Please note: This is NOT a question about how data should better be stored. But wheither regexp replaces are possible or not. The example is only demonstrative to simplify the question and it's nature.

Comment: Shouldn't this check be applied while entering values in database ? That would save the pain of checking it while retrieving.

Comment: Don't use the database to store formatted values. Formatting should be done by functions upon retrieval, either in MySql or PHP.

Comment: In the MySQL documentation I found this: "The REPLACE function does not support regular expression so if you need to replace a text string by a pattern you need to use MySQL user-defined function (UDF) from external library, check it out here MySQL UDF with Regex."

Comment: Thank you for all your feedback that a better shot is to keep the input data to database in a consistent format. I would like the thread to focus on whither or not there is a regexp_replace possibility in MySQL regardless of the actual cases or examples.

Comment: What version are you using?  Only MariaDB has `regexp_replace()`.

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.6.29

Answer (score 2):

You can improve your application using this 2 steps:

- write migration which convert you data with different formats to one
  canonical
- move formatting of this values to your view layer

This approach gives you:

- ease in searching by this field
- flexibility in using different formats for this field in differents views